# How to open & close react-bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I'm new to react and I'm working with react-bootstrap. I have a perfectly working react app with 2 components and I'm using function components. Here is the code.

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => setModalShow(true)}>
        Launch vertically centered modal
      </Button>

      <MyVerticallyCenteredModal
        show={modalShow}
        onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

**MyVerticallyCenteredModal.js**

```
export default function MyVerticallyCenteredModal(props) {
    return (
        <Modal
            {...props}
            size="lg"
            aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
            centered
        >
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                    Modal heading
            </Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                <h4>Centered Modal</h4>
                <p>
                    Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio,
                    dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac
                    consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
            </p>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button onClick={props.onHide}>Close</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    );
}
```

At this stage, my code is working fine. But I need to make a few changes. I need to remove show and onHide props from *MyVerticallyCenteredModal* component and access props from *Modal* component. Here is what I did,

**App.js**

```
<MyVerticallyCenteredModal />
```

**MyVerticallyCenteredModal.js**

```
<Modal
  show={modalShow}
  onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
  size="lg"
  aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
  centered
>
...
</Modal>
```

Now I'm getting a compile error,

```
'modalShow' is not defined
'setModalShow' is not defined
```

But without moving useState from App.js to MyVerticallyCenteredModal.js how can I do it?

Comment: Can we declare the state in Modal. I didn't understood the last line of your question :)

Comment: Basically, I don't want to add a new state or remove the current useState

Comment: And also you have written you cannot pass props to Modal right?

Comment: Do one thing Vicky. Put your code on Codesandbox and share then link with me. I will surely try to help you out :)

Comment: Actually, I want to use show={} and onHide={} in the <Modal /> component

Comment: But this has to be done based on some state as React works on state and modifies DOM.Wait Wait I got a trick. Just place your full code with dependencies on codesandbox. I will try to do it without adding any other state  ... At least I can try a non state approach

Comment: Ok here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-mirzakhani-o8ryp?file=/src/MyVerticallyCenteredModal.js)

Comment: let me see it my friend :)

Comment: I got it. I want to know something from you. Can I modify the code in Modal Component without using state but by other technique :)

Comment: Listen bro, Even if you sit for hours, Since you are rendering the Modal Component in the App component and App component has the button to initiate the modal open. Then in basic React it is not possible to do this without passing props.

Comment: These props have to be passed. Because only the parent controls state of child.You can use Context-API or Redux as a solution but that will be too much code.

Answer (score 0):

The onClick(); should take an event as for controlling mouse click:

```
 onClick={(e) => {setModalShow(false)}};
```

Same for onHide();

Note: you can also use the word 'event' instead of the letter 'e'

Comment: Sorry, I got the same error 'setModalShow' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The states is controlled from the Parent Component `<App/>` and the `button` that launches the `Modal` is in the App component.

```
  <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => setModalShow(true)}>
    Launch vertically centered modal
  </Button>
```

So, it is not possible to control the Modal behaviour from the Modal itsef.

But yes if you directly render your `Modal` in the `<App/>` Component itself without using a Parent Component for rendering of Modal. Then this can be done.

We will need a small button inside the modal component and use state in Modal itself to control that :)